# XSL Transformation of XML - Simple .NET example?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have a.NET based application that receives an incoming XML file. I would like to transform the XML file into HTML using an XSL stylesheet I have. This is my process ...

1. Read the submitted XML file from filesystem
2. Apply XSL to XML for transformation
3. Print resultant HTML to screen as HTML

Does anyone have any example code that demonstrates how to to this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the many tutorials that cover this, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912472.aspx ?  When posting questions on SO you should first make an effort to answer them yourself, and then bring up specific questions on what you've tried.  We're all volunteers here and are not going to do your work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Just out of curiosity, why do you assume I didn't look for the answer before asking the question?

Comment: @John - While you consider the answer to be easy to find and understand, others may not. Remember, before you and Jim were where you are today you probably had questions that those with more experience also thought were simple and "easy to find and understand".

Comment: @web: well, no, I was in the habit of looking at the MSDN documentation and figuring it out on my own.

Comment: Of course, you never needed assistance or asked someone else a question. Your arrogance is astounding, but not entirely unexpected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here is a very short example from the [MSDN .NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163434.aspx)** on using the **[`Transform()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70k6zz96.aspx)** method of the **[`XslCompiledTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163414.aspx)** class that is a standard part of .NET (implemented in the **[`System.Xml.Xsl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70k6zz96.aspx)** namespace):

```
// Load the style sheet.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("output.xsl");

// Create the FileStream.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\data\output.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
   // Execute the transformation.
   xslt.Transform(new XPathDocument("books.xml"), null, fs);
}
```

What remains to be done is to invoke the browser and pass the result of the transformation, contained in the stream `fs` to it. If efficiency is important, one can choose to use memory stream over file stream.

**You should get acquainted with the other overloads of** the **[`Transform()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163429.aspx)** ***method and choose the one that is best for you**.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually said which XSLT processor you are using. There are at least three available: the Microsoft one, which only supports XSLT 1.0, and Saxon and XQSharp which both support XSLT 2.0. All unfortunately have different APIs.

Answer (score 0):

A good example from a somewhat related post - [Passing null to `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941449/passing-null-to-xslcompiledtransform-transform-method/5941579#5941579)