# Passing null to `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` method

Tags: .net, xml, parameters, null

I am trying to transform and XML document using XSL. I am not too familiar with how to transform XML in .NET so I am using some example code ...

```
XslCompiledTransform xslTransformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslTransformer.Load(Server.MapPath("Test.xslt"));

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xslTransformer.Transform(Server.MapPath("Test.xml"), null, ms);

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
string output = sr.ReadToEnd();
ms.Close();

Response.Write(output);
```

The problem I am running into is the following line ...

```
xslTransformer.Transform(Server.MapPath("Test.xml"), null, ms);
```

The compiler is showing an error in passing in `null` to the Transform method. In looking at the `Transform` method signatures it looks like the parameter `null` is representing is various options for the transformation. The Visual Studio IDE even shows that this value can be `null`. I also tried using `DBNull.Value` but that also shows an error. Any idea what I am missing?

UPDATE: The error I am receiving is two-fold. (1) First I am told that `null` is no longer supported and I should use `System.DBNull`. (2) Once I change `null` to `System.DBNull` I get an error saying `overload resolution failed because no accessible Transform can be called with these arguments.`

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a different [XslCompiledTransform.Transform method overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform.aspx), the one which accepts [a String path and an XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163432.aspx):

```
XslCompiledTransform xslTransformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslTransformer.Load(Server.MapPath("Test.xslt"));

// XmlWriter allows you to specify additional settings
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
settings.CloseOutput = false;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
    {
        xslTransformer.Transform(Server.MapPath("Test.xml"), writer);
    }

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    string output = sr.ReadToEnd();
    ms.Close();
}

Response.Write(output);
```

Actually, if you are only interesting in rendering XML to a string, you can use a [`StringBuilder` as the target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66dybzaw.aspx), without a `MemoryStream`, and simplify your code to:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslTransformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslTransformer.Load(Server.MapPath("Test.xslt"));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{
    xslTransformer.Transform(Server.MapPath("Test.xml"), writer);
}

Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

**[Edit]** (based on your comment)

If the input XML is in a string, then you can use yet another `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` method overload: [`Transform(XmlReader, XmlWriter)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163433.aspx).

`XmlReader` can be (among other ways) instantiated using a concrete implementation of `TextReader`, in this case a [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx). You can also use an other stream as input.

When you put all that together, you should end up with:

```
string input = @"<SomeXml />"
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
using (StringReader strReader = new StringReader(input))
{
   using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strReader))
   {
      using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output))
      {
          xslTransformer.Transform(reader, writer);
      }
   }
}
Response.Write(output.ToString());
```

All of these classes implement `IDisposable`, so you need to make sure they are disposed after use.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent example @Groo. What if one already had the XML as a string, instead of having exist as a file?

Comment: Thank you so much for adding the update. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the middle argument that's causing the error? Perhaps `Server.MapPath("Test.xml")` is returning null?