# How to generate HTML from a site using the XML

Tags: java, javascript, html

I'm not a developer, nor know much of anything about java , so looking for advice on ways that this can be done.

This web host service allows its users to pull data from their XML sheets and place them anywhere on your own site(still hosted by same company). By using their developers program you can access the XML sheets for a variety of items.

Example test site
http://www23.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/61760

Developers Program
http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export

and when you select the info you want, and enter in your league ID , you get the XML sheet
http://football23.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=appearance&L=61760&W=&JSON=0

So how would one go about , taking that information from the XML sheet and using it to place the content on all the pages of their site , hosted on the main host server ?

Answer (score 1):

1) *"Java" <> "JavaScript"*.  Q: Which language (if either) are you actually using?

2) The canonical answer for "generate HTML from XML" is to use XSL stylesheets.

- Here's a good XSLT overview: [XSLT Languages](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_languages.asp)
- Here's a Java/Servlet-oriented link: http://ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipxsltzen
- Here are some C#/.Net oriented links:

  [XSL Tansformation of XML: Simple .Net example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940766/xsl-transformation-of-xml-simple-net-example)

  http://codem8.blogspot.com/2011/11/xml-to-html-using-xslt-and-c-i-was.html